# Numpy.matrix not recognized

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, liclipse

New to python; running windows.  I am using python27, and ran the following code.  It failed, even though it recognized numpy.  Then, I made sure that numpy was installed by running pip install numpy.  Reran the code and had the same problem: `numpy` was recognized, and a list of classes in the auto-suggest populates, but not `numpy.matrix`.  I can't seem to find any indication that this should be a problem.  It seems to just work...

```
import numpy

board = numpy.matrix([0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0])
```

It compiles, but the `numpy.matrix` still has a red line under it.  the popup message when I mouse over it says: `undefined variable from import: matrix`

How do I enable the matrix class?
Or am I dealing with a Liclipse error? (Liclipse is my IDE)

Numpy is getting imported from:

```
module 'numpy' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyc'
```

Comment: Please give the complete, exact error message.

Comment: By the way, if you are trying to create a 5x5 matrix of zeros, you are missing an outer level of brackets: `board = numpy.matrix([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])`

Comment: Can you check that it is importing  numpy from the correct path using `print(numpy)`.

Comment: OK, that looks reasonable. Can you try running the numpy test suite (`numpy.test()`)?